# Can you use a .exe project as a library in another project in the same solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

As title says. I'm adding a project to an existing open source solution and would like to use some of the functionality of its .exe tools in my project. I added it as a reference and added its directory to additional includes but I cant seem to include its header file.

Comment: In short, you can't. Extract everything from your executable besides the `main()` function into a separate library. Thus you can link it for both purposes.

Comment: aw :/ I thought there might be some way since the project checks for "NOMAIN" definition in which case it skips the main function and has export declarations for all its functions. That wouldn't make much sense for a console only application. Could I possibly do something programmatically to make it compile to a library instead when compiled from my project? I'm trying to modify the source material as little as possible.